# Repository Pattern or not? ORM needed? MVC Web api REST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am pretty new to building restful web api's but I have been doing a lot of studying and have a strong understanding of the basics.  I have built a service for my company using the latest best practices of web api 2.  Attribute routing and route prefixes, dependency injection, and more.  I think my service is pretty solid, but there is a possible need of a refactor.

My company is considering moving away from MS SQL to PostGreSql or possibly a different database solution.  Also, I should mention that we do not use EF or any other ORM.  The reason for us not using EF is because our DB schema is constantly changing and we have numerous environments that are often different from each other(dev, qa, prod, etc).  So we have developed our own framework to handle our queries to the databases.  We use stored procedures pretty regularly to retrieve data.

So, changing my service to accommodate a different DB, it seems that a repository pattern would be the solution.  However, when I start researching into it, it feels like we are adding a lot of overhead code when in fact, it might be less code to write to just go back and refactor the service if the DB change actually happens.  For each of my controllers I would need to write a IModelRepository and ModelRepository class at the least.

Can anyone provide any guidance on this?

Edit:

I'm not really sure how to make this question less broad.  I don't know enough about repository patterns to be more detailed in my question.  I basically, just wanted to know if repository pattern is the solution to the issue of possibly changing DB solutions in the future in a web api MVC service even if I am not  using an ORM like entity framework?

I ask because every example I find online seems to use EF which makes it hard to relate to my current issue.  However, the top answer gives a really good explanation and I think my question is answered.  I just need to find a good resource to learn the pattern from.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Repository pattern tries to avoid *tight coupling* of your *domain* with *data-mapping layer* (or just call it *data layer*), which is occasionally dependent to underlying data technology of choice.

While you might feel that's useless in your concrete use case, I'll try to convince you with a very simple argument: **data-access details will be enforced in your repositories and this means that your data strategy will be self-contained there**. In other words: your domain will remain agnostic to data-access approach, and you won't need to change thousands and thousands of code lines if you need to change this in the future.

Conclusion: even in your scenario repository pattern is useful. Leave your domain code to just solve domain issues rather than mixing everything in a true spaguetti code!

### The inversion of control story...

When repository pattern meets *inversion of control* everything gets more powerful, since you can switch how your domain translate to data by configuration, and you enforce even more **loose coupling** and and *separation of concerns*.

Beat this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not using EF seems to be the mistake. EF would be the repository that abstracts away the database to a large extent. You want to be able to target different database products. EF is good at that.

Introduce Entity Framework to solve the problem.

Comment: BTW it seems like this should be a comment...

Comment: No, this is my advice for what he should do.

Comment: I raised this as a solution, but there are performance concerns when choosing EF.

Comment: Those concerns are probably there because you don't understand how to use EF. The number of cases where perf is a problem *because of EF* and not because of misuse is small. Maybe you should do a prototype and investigate query translation in detail.

Comment: If you feel that it shouldn't be a comment... For me, this should be a comment because it doesn't address the issue at all... It's just: hey, use EF, you're wrong (and I'm agree after all, I hate the argument "I did an OR/M because EF or NHib are slow"... who knows what code hell could be that custom OR/M, I'm a lucky man since I don't need to collaborate on that Project!!)...

Comment: `System.Data` and `System.Data.Common` namespaces provide classes to abstract the database as well. ORM is not necessary for that.